# Calculus on equations with 2 variables

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Suppose $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $$x^2 + y^2 - xy = 10.$$ What is the maximum value of $60(x^2 + y^2 + xy)$?

---

I transposed the variables and used substitution and obtained $1200$ as the answer. I just want to be definite if my answer is correct.

Comment: For next time, know that you can enclose _whole expressions_ in dollar signs (i.e. write `$x^2 + y^2 -xy = 10$` rather than `$x^2$ + $y^2$ = 10`). That both saves time and looks better.

Comment: Show your actual work, in your post, whenever you claim you've done this or that.  In other words, don't claim to have tried... unless you include **how** you obtained 1200, including all your workings in your question post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Lagrange multipliers method:
$$L=60(x^2+y^2+xy)+t(10-x^2-y^2+xy).$$
$$\begin{cases} L_x=120x+60y-2xt+ty=0 \\ L_y=120y+60x-2yt+tx=0 \\ L_t=10-x^2-y^2+xy=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow\begin{cases} x_{1,2}=y_{1,2}=\pm \sqrt{10} \\ x_{3,4}=-y_{3,4}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{10}{3}}\end{cases}$$
Hence:
$$f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)=1800 - max;$$
$$f(x_3,y_3)=f(x_4,y_4)=200 - min.$$

Comment: Can you please provide a reference

Comment: If you mean LP method, here they are: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier or http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I got $1800$ because
$$60(x^2+xy+y^2)\leq1800\cdot\frac{x^2-xy+y^2}{10}$$ it's
$$3(x^2-xy+y^2)\geq x^2+xy+y^2,$$ which is
$$(x-y)^2\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y$, which says that $1800$ is a maximal value.

Comment: Please elaborate